# How can I skip increments in R 'for' loop?

Tags: r, algorithm, for-loop

I need to find stretches of values above 0 in a numeric vector where there are at least 10 members within each region. I do not want to check every single position as it would be very time intensive (vector is over 10 million).

Here is what I'm trying to do (very preliminary as I can't figure out how to skip increments in for loop):

```
1. Check if x[i] (start position) is positive. 
  a) if positive, check to see if x[i+10] (end position) is positive (since we want at least length 10 of positive integers)
    * if positive, check every position in between to see if positive
    * if negative, move to x[i+11], skip positions (e.g. new start position is x[i+12]) in between start & end positions since we would not get >10 members if negative end position is included. 


x <- rnorm(50, mean=0, sd=4)
for(i in 1:length(x)){
  if(x[i]>0){ # IF START POSITION IS POSITIVE
    flag=1
    print(paste0(i, ": start greater than 1"))
    if(x[i+10]>0){ # IF END POSITION POSITIVE, THEN CHECK ALL POSITIONS IN BETWEEN
      for(j in i+1:i+9){
        if(x[j]>0){ # IF POSITION IS POSITIVE, CHECK NEXT POSITION IF POSITIVE
          print(paste0(j, ": for j1")) 
        }else{ # IF POSITION IS NEGATIVE, THEN SKIP CHECKING & SET NEW START POSITION
          print(paste0(j, ": for j2"))  
          i <- i+11
          break;
        }
      }
    }else{ # IF END POSITION IS NOT POSITIVE, START CHECK ONE POSITION AFTER END POSITION
      i <- i+11
    }
  }
}
```

The issue I have is that even when I manually increment `i`, the for loop `i` value masks the new set value. Appreciate any insight.

Comment: This doesn't work, what if numbers at positions 8 through 18 are positive, you are at 11 (which is where you end up after position 1 is negative) and number at 21 is negative? You won't detect this stretch

Comment: That is correct. I didn't include that as I haven't had a chance to work at it. If start is negative, end is positive, then it would be necessary to backtrack from end position to find the start of the positive stretch.

Comment: A vectorized approach will probably be faster than a for loop, even with big data. Something like `rle(x > 0)` will be fast.

Comment: If you insist on using a loop, the way you're approaching things is more like a `while` loop. The point of a `for` loop is to set up in advance all possible values of `i`, and then go through them one at a time. Trying to jump around and manipulate `i` will be difficult. Perhaps you could use a `while` loop instead? `i <- 1; while(i < length(x))`...  it won't auto-increment and will rely on your commands inside the loop to modify `i`, so you can easily increment by 1 or 10 or however much as appropriate.

Comment: Appreciate the insight. Thank you, @Gregor

Comment: You can do this with `for` loop like this: `for (m in 1:floor (length (x)/10)) { i <- m * 10; ... }`

Comment: Lev has a nice approach if you're only interested in regions starting at indices 1, 11, 21, etc. If you're interested in all runs of at least 10, regardless of where they start, then `rle` is your friend.

Comment: the R equivalent for continue/pass is next

Answer (score 2):

I dunno if this approach is as efficient as Curt F's, but how about

```
runs <- rle(x>0)
```

And then working with the regions defined by `runs$lengths>10 & runs$values ==TRUE` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that finds stretches of ten positive numbers in a vector of length ten million. It does not use the loop approach suggested in the OP.

The idea here is to take the cumulative sum of the logical expression `vec>0`.  The difference between position n and n-10 will be 10 only if all values of the vector at positions between n-10 and n are positive.

`filter` is an easy and relatively fast way to calculate these differences.

```
#generate random data
vec   <- runif(1e7,-1,1)

#cumulative sum
csvec <- cumsum(vec>0)   

#construct a filter that will find the difference between the nth value with the n-10th value of the cumulative sign vector
f11   <- c(1,rep(0,9),-1)

#apply the filter
fv    <- filter(csvec, f11, sides = 1) 

#find where the difference as computed by the filter is 10
inds  <- which(fv == 10)

#check a few results
> vec[(inds[1]-9):(inds[1])]
 [1] 0.98457526 0.03659257 0.77507743 0.69223183 0.70776891 0.34305865 0.90249491 0.93019927 0.18686722 0.69973176
> vec[(inds[2]-9):(inds[2])]
 [1] 0.0623790 0.8489058 0.3783840 0.8781701 0.6193165 0.6202030 0.3160442 0.3859175 0.8416434 0.8994019
> vec[(inds[200]-9):(inds[200])]
 [1] 0.0605163 0.7921233 0.3879834 0.6393018 0.2327136 0.3622615 0.1981222 0.8410318 0.3582605 0.6530633

#check all the results
> prod(sapply(1:length(inds),function(x){prod(sign(vec[(inds[x]-9):(inds[x])]))}))
[1] 1
```

I played around with `system.time()` to see how long the various steps took.  On my not-very-powerful laptop the longest step was `filter()`, which took just over half a second for a vector of length ten million.

Answer (score 1):

Vectorised solution using only basic commands:

```
x <- runif(1e7,-1,1)  # generate random vector

y <- which(x<=0)  # find boundaries i.e. negatives and zeros
dif <- y[2:length(y)] - y[1:(length(y)-1)]  # find distance in boundaries
drange <- which(dif > 10)  # find distances more than 10

starts <- y[drange]+1  # starting positions of sequence
ends <- y[drange+1]-1  # last positions of sequence
```

The first range you want is from `x[starts[1]]` to `x[ends[1]]` , etc.